# Алиас пути работает двояко - Yii2

Tags: yii2, alias

Добрый день.
У меня такая проблема:
В Yii2 advanced, в ***common/config/bootsrap.php*** создал ***@alias*** в котором нужно хранить фотографии, но есть проблема:

- если скрипт работает на ***frontend*** - тогда @папка создается
  в public_html/uploads
- а если скрипт рабоатет на ***backend*** - тогда @папка
  создается в public_html/admin/uploads/.

Как сделать так чтобы папка создавалсь только в frontend?

Дополнительная информация:

- [Структра папок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w9rJ.png)
- [.htaccess - код для обоих файлов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUxjD.png)

Код для: 
**backend**/controllers/ActionкоторыйСоздаетДиректорию

```
$dir = Yii::getAlias('@images') . '/blog/';
FileHelper::createDirectory($dir);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал следующе изменения:
Yii::setAlias('@images', dirname(dirname(dirname(*DIR*))) . '/../uploads/images');
и работает.